# how to get list of servers from openstack using python

Tags: openstack-nova

I am very new to openstack and python

I have tried to get list of servers from openstack.. here is the code

credentials.py

```
  import os
  def get_nova_credentials_v2():
  d = {}
  d['version'] = '2'
  d['username'] = os.environ['billing']
  d['password'] = os.environ['mypassword']
  d['auth_url'] = os.environ['my auth url']
  d['project_id'] = os.environ['projectname']
  return d
```

instance.py

```
  from credentials import get_nova_credentials_v2
  from novaclient.client import Client

  credentials = get_nova_credentials_v2()
  nova_client = Client(**credentials)

  print(nova_client.servers.list())
```

I get the error

```
    C:\Python27\python.exe C:/Users/ICEClenovos/PycharmProjects/billing/instance.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/ICEClenovos/PycharmProjects/billing/instance.py", line 5, in <module>
     credentials = get_nova_credentials_v2()
     File "C:\Users\ICEClenovos\PycharmProjects\billing\credentials.py", line 7, in
     get_nova_credentials_v2    
     d['username'] = os.environ['billing']
     File "C:\Python27\lib\os.py", line 423, in __getitem__
     return self.data[key.upper()]
 KeyError: 'BILLING'

  Process finished with exit code 1
```

Don't know where I am doing wrong..Please help

Comment: Is your environment variable BILLING set? Accordingly to your Python script, no: that error means that the key 'BILLING' is not set in the dictionary os.environ.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to get the server details from the Openstack you don't need to source Biling details. grab the credentials available in your "stackrc / openrc" file.

we are calling servers.list() with nova object. similarly you can play around with instance details, and get more info about instance [here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/python-novaclient/ref/v2/servers.html)

```
  from novaclient import client as novaclient

nova = novaclient.Client(version='2.0',username='xxxx',api_key='xxxx',project_id='xxxx',auth_url='http://192.168.12.3:5000/v2.0/',insecure='True')

for server in nova.servers.list():
    print server.id, server.name
```